# How to Debug XPath Processing using XMLDataSource in Jasperreports Library

Tags: java, xpath, jasper-reports

As you will see, this is a Jasperreports logging question.  I am trying to generate a PDF report from an XML file using Jasperreports Library (so no server products here).  After designing a report using iReport I execute the following Java statement:

```
JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfFile("bin/EstateAccountingMonthly.jasper",
                                    m_outputPdfFileName,
                                    parameters,
                                    xmlDataSource);
```

This statement grinds away for about 30 seconds, produces no exceptions, writes very little to the log file and produces a one page empty PDF file.  The parameter `xmlDataSource` references an XML file whose structure DOES NOT match the XPath expressions contained in the report.  This is because the schema of the XML file changed without reflecting those changes in the Jasper report files (i.e. the .JRXML files).  So I'm not expecting to get a good report (or any report).  But what I was expecting was Jasper telling me that various XPath expressions were failing during the production of the report against the XML stream.  But Jasper reported nothing (in the log file, which is configured to log ALL events).

I don't know how to configure Jasper to report the attempts and results of XPath expression evaluations.  I wound up doing something desperate (which didn't work): combing through the Jasper jar file looking for classes whose name suggests it might generate the type of logging I'm looking for and then incorporating those classes in the `log4j.properties` file:

```
# Extra logging related to initialization of Log4j
# Set to debug or trace if log4j initialization is failing
status = all
# Name of the configuration
name = ConsoleLogConfigDemo

# Console appender configuration
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger level
rootLogger.level = all
# Root logger referring to console appender
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger

# The following are my best guesses for which classes should be enabled for logging.

logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_data_jrxmldatasource.name=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.jrxmldatasource
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_data_jrxmldatasource.level=ALL
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_data_jrxmldatasource.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger

logger.net_sf_jasperreports_data_xml_XmlDataAdapterImpl.name=net.sf_jasperreports.data.xml.XmlDataAdapterImpl
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_data_xml_XmlDataAdapterImpl.level=ALL
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_data_xml_XmlDataAdapterImpl.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger

logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_util_xml_JRXPathExecuter.name=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JRXPathExecuter
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_util_xml_JRXPathExecuter.level=ALL
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_util_xml_JRXPathExecuter.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger

logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_util_xml_XalanXPathExecuter.name=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.XalanXPathExecuter
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_util_xml_XalanXPathExecuter.level=ALL
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_util_xml_XalanXPathExecuter.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger

logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_query_XalanXPathQueryExecuter.name=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.XalanXPathQueryExecuter
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_query_XalanXPathQueryExecuter.level=ALL
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_query_XalanXPathQueryExecuter.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger

logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_util_xml_JRXPathExecuterUtils.name=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JRXPathExecuterUtils
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_util_xml_JRXPathExecuterUtils.level=ALL
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_util_xml_JRXPathExecuterUtils.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger

logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_query_JRXPathQueryExecuter.name=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRXPathQueryExecuter
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_query_JRXPathQueryExecuter.level=ALL
logger.net_sf_jasperreports_engine_query_JRXPathQueryExecuter.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger
```

But this did not cause logging of XPath evaluations to occur.  How do I debug XPath evaluations?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth considering that when an XPath processor evaluates an XPath expression and returns an empty result, that's not a "failure" from the point of view of the XPath processor; that's a success. A "failure" is when the XPath expression is invalid, but of course these expressions are all valid.

I suspect that you will probably have more luck by taking the XML input,  collecting these XPath expressions from the report, and then debugging them in an external tool, such as a web browser's console, or a website like https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html or https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/